# Installed IBM DB2 and created sample database. Database has been created but not able to see any tables in it

Tags: database, db2

Sample database was created but got a glitch while creating and now iam not able to see the tables. How to deleted or drop the db and create a new sample db.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop and recreate the sample database on demand.

To do this, you can use a command line.

On Microsoft-Windows, start > run > db2cwadmin.bat  > db2 drop database sample

On Linux bash shell , sudo to the instance-owner (for example `su - db2inst1` ) and then run `db2 drop database sample`

You can recreate the sample database by running the `db2sampl` command in the same window as the one you used for dropping the database.

You can also give options , additional parameters, to the `db2sampl` command line to choose a different database-name or other characteristics. Refer to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001934.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

=> **db2 drop database sample**
This command is used to drop the database sample. But few things should be taken care of.
We cannot drop active database or a connected database.

db2 => **list active databases**  // This command will show if sample is active(connected) or not.

If it is active use **disconnect sample** command and try drop command again.